# edit text on blank page?

Tags: titles

As my title, how do I put the text and footer on the blank page which after every title page? This is my code so far, but this only effect on the blank page before the title page!Also I use python and json to load the data.

Sorry for late updating, this is the completed code which I use for my json file but it also  has the same problem. I think there may has some conflict problem between my code, but I don't know how to fix it. Is anyone know where's the problem? Thank you very much.
[page 6 is the blankpage before title page, page 7 is title page and page 8 is the blankpage after title page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrRkz.png)

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,textwidth=7.25in,textheight=9in,top=1in,bottom=1in,headsep=0.125in,footskip=0.125in,left=0.75in,right=0.5in,twoside}

\geometry{marginparsep = 0.5in}

\titlecontents{section}[5em]{}{\vspace{.1em} \hspace{-2.5em} }{}    {\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[4pt]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]{}{}{}{}

\setmainfont[Mapping=text-tex]{Calibri}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} 
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0.3,.7,0.3}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.3, 0.3, .6}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{.6,.6,.6}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\voffset = 0pt
\hoffset = 0pt

%force section start with new page
\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}


\newcommand{\delppart}[1]{\part{#1}}
\newcommand{\delpsection}[1]{\section{#1}}
\newcommand{\delpsubsection}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
\newcommand{\delpsubsubsection}[1]{\subsubsection{#1}}
\newcommand{\delpsubsubsubsection}[0]{\subsubsubsection}
\newcommand{\bulletl}[0]{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\checkl}[0]{\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\checkmark$}}
\newcommand{\figurebottom}[1]{\begin{figure}[b]#1\end{figure}}
\newcommand{\twocol}[1]{\begin{multicols}{2}{#1}\end{multicols}}
\newcommand{\greenrow}[1]{\rowcolor{green}#1}
\newcommand{\bluerow}[1]{\rowcolor{blue}#1}
\newcommand{\greyrow}[1]{\rowcolor{grey}#1}
\newcommand{\white}[1]{\color{white}#1}
\newcommand{\none}[1]{#1}


\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%footnote

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf[]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{ \normalsize  BlahBlahBlahBlah\\BlahBlahBlahBlah}
\fancyfoot[C]{- \thepage\  -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{
\fancyhf[]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{ \normalsize  BlahBlahBlahBlah\\BlahBlahBlahBlah}
\fancyfoot[C]{- \thepage\  -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\fancyhead[R]{\Huge \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{ \normalsize BlahBlahBlahBlah\\BlahBlahBlahBlah}
\fancyfoot[C]{- \thepage\  -}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{%
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage\hfill\else\fi\rule{2.5in}{\footrulewidth}\vskip\footruleskip}

\newcommand*\BPText{THIS PAGE IS INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK.}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{%
\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{2.125in}
\begin{center}
\BPText
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\dontbreak}[1]{\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\noinfo}[0]{-}
\newcommand{\defaultnum}[1]{\numprint{#1}}
\newcommand{\percentage}[1]{\numprint{#1}\%}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{\normalfont \huge\raggedleft  \vspace{0.6in} \titlerule}{}{-70pt}{#1\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0pt}{}


\newcommand{\defaulttabletitlemacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultcoltitlerowmacro}[1]{\greenrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultcoltitleitemmacro}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultrowmacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultitemmacro}[1]{ \hspace*{\fill}#1}
\newcommand{\defaultrowtitlemacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsumrowmacro}[1]{\greenrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsubsumrowmacro}[1]{\greyrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsubsubsumrowmacro}[1]{\greyrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsumitemmacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsubsumitemmacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsubsubsumitemmacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultdiffrowmacro}[1]{\bluerow{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultdiffitemmacro}[1]{\hspace*{\fill}#1}
\newcommand{\defaultdifftitlemacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsumtitlemacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsubsumtitlemacro}[1]{\none{#1}}
\newcommand{\defaultsubsubsumtitlemacro}[1]{\none{#1}}

\newcommand{\defaultsubtabletitlemacro}[1]{ \textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\centerit}[1]{\begin{center}\itshape{#1}\end{center}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
\par\nobreak % don't break a page here
\vspace{0.01in} 
\kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
\kern#2 % space before the rule
{\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
\kern#1 % space after the rule
\nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}

\newcommand{\goalheader}[1]{#1\myrule[3pt][0pt][green]}
\nprounddigits{2}


\begin{document}


\part{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1-37]
\part{Test Chapter Two}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? It's not clear to me where do you want the text to appear. Can you please add to your question a simple, but *complete* skeleton of your document?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I agree, the question is unclear. I *think* that the OP would like to style the blank pages created by the `\cleardoublepage` command

Comment: @cmhughes -- if `\cleardoublepage` is modified, that would affect every single blank page in the document.  if it's a book, that's potentially after the table of contents and every chapter.  not a good idea.

Comment: @jrsy -- what document class are you using?  and do you mean just the "cover" title page, or something else?

Comment: @barbarabeeton according to the OP's comment to my answer, a redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` seems to be what is needed; however, a problem persists that will have to wait for more information from the OP.

Comment: Thanks for adding information. However, we still need some more code; we need to see exactly the code that you are using for pages 6, 7 and 8. An image alone doesn't tell us where the problem might be. Please add to your question the complete code used to produce those pages, in the form of a small and complete document.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if something like this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*\BPText{THIS PAGE IS INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK.}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{%
  \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \centering
  \BPText
  \vspace{\fill}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left the original `plain` style for the blank pages which makes even more odd the message (those pages are not really blank: they contain some text and a page number).

Comment: Yes, this is the thing I need...but the blank page after title is still blank. only the blank page before title page works...do you know how to fix it?thank you!

Comment: @Jrsy bwithout seeing how exactly you are building your title page and which document class you are using it's almost impossible to give effective advise. Please, as I suggested in a comment to your question, add a minimal, *complete* document showing the relevant settings involved.