# Showing 'intentionally blank' page at the last odd page of book

Tags: books, book-design, blank-page

I want to start every chapter from an odd page and the corresponding blank pages should appear with the notice "The page is intentionally left blank". I have achieved it in my MWE. But I also want to keep the last odd page (before the back cover) blank with the same 'intentionally blank' notice. I couldn't generate it.

In my MWE, there are 10 pages. The 9th page is appearing full empty. But I like to show the 'intentionally blank' notice in it, similar to the 8th page.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}                              
  \chead{Book's Title}
  \cfoot{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}
\usepackage[demo]{pdfpages}
% Commnad for blank page texts         % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66901/114006
\newcommand*\bptext{The page is intentionally left blank}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{%
  \clearpage\if@twoside\ifodd\c@page\else
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \begin{center}
  \small\bptext
  \end{center}
  \vfill 
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Book's Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf{front_cover}   % the front cover page is added here
\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\pagestyle{empty} 
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage           

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{First Chapter}                          
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage \   

\includepdf{back_cover}  % the back cover page is added here

\end{document}
```

Basically, if my last chapter ends at an odd page, it should generate two 'intentionally blank' pages before the last page (back cover). And if my last chapter ends at an even page, it should generate one 'intentionally blank' page before the last page. So, in both cases, my book should always end with the last page (back cover) at an even page. How can I do it?

Comment: A search of 'intentionally blank'  in this site showed 132 question about the subject. Most  probably, some of these can help you.

Comment: @Fran I have searched for it, but couldn't manage to solve my issue.

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't have to set the page numbering style if you use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`. After `\frontmatter`, the chapters are not numbered, but appear in the TOC.

Comment: simply define a `\clearpagebeforebackcover` command which implements the logic you are describing in words.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, please post an answer showing your suggested command.

Answer (score 0):

To help you on your way, the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report` classes) provides several macros for going to another page in addition to the normal `\clear(double)page`. For example

```
\movetoevenpage[<text>]
```

stops the current page and starts typesetting on the next even numbered page; the optional `<text>`, if specified is put on the skipped page (if there is one).

There are also `\cleartoevenpage`, which flushes out any floats before moving on, and similarly `\movetooddpage`, `\cleartooddpage`

I feel that the `memoir` *go-to-page* macros will help you.

Comment: I simply can't switch from `book` to `memoir`, right? It would be more helpful if you showed the necessary changes in my MWE.

Comment: Did you try switching from `book` to `memoir`? \documentclass{memoir}` basically produces the same result as `\documentclass{book}`. You can always look at the `memoir` code for *go-to-page* macros and copy them them into your document.

Comment: I replaced `book` by `memoir` in my question's MWE. It's giving a LaTeX Error: `Environment titlepage undefined. [\begin{titlepage}]`.

Comment: @raf Try the `titlingpage` environment instead of `titlepage`. See the manual (`texdoc memoir`) section **4.1 STYLING THE TITLING**.